# Set postgres password with hash

Tags: postgresql

I need to clone role from one postgresql database to another. Is it possible to somehow extract role password hash and set it in another database ? I'd like to avoid any clear password manipulation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PostgreSQL thinks you're setting the password with an MD5 hash, it stores it directly. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html)

> If the presented password string is already in MD5-encrypted format, then it is stored encrypted as-is, regardless of whether ENCRYPTED or UNENCRYPTED is specified (since the system cannot decrypt the specified encrypted password string). This allows reloading of encrypted passwords during dump/restore.

Answer (score 1):

you can select password from `pg_shadow` and use it as per docs, as Eavn told. Or you can use `pg_dumpall -g` which will basically prepare statements to run with md5 passwords eg. at my machine:

```
CREATE ROLE r;
ALTER ROLE r WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5514f1b439f404f86f77090fa9edc96ce';
```